# Is it suitable to use VM to run benchmark testing?

Tags: virtual-machine

compared with physical machine, the VM is much more easy to change the machine scale and spec,   do you think using VM(VirtualBox, or VMWare) to run benchmark is reasonable or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're only comparing code executed in a VM to other code executed using the same VM program, OS, and virtual architecture, and don't expect the numbers to compare reasonably with benchmarks obtained while running native code in an actual processor, you shouldn't have any trouble using a VM for benchmarking to simulate weaker machines than your actual PC

Comment: Does this also extend to VMs running in the cloud, i.e. would you recommend or at least say it's reasonable to run benchmarks on a VPS in the cloud?